# How to give access to a file only for particular user group?

Tags: batch-file, powershell, powershell-2.0, acl

we are trying to restrict the access to an exe only to a group of users.

By default, Administrators also inherited the access.

How to remove the inheritance to administrators and provide access only to the User group name say "Special log Admin"?

Comment: This question should be on Serverfault. Use Applocker.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730951.aspx and here https://www.angryadmin.co.uk/?p=425

```
$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl"

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("BUILTIN\Users")

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule `
    ($objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType)

$objACL = Get-ACL "C:\Scripts\Test.ps1"
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE)

#!!!Remove the parent folder inheritance and don't copy the previously inherited permissions.
$objAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)

Set-ACL "C:\Scripts\Test.ps1" $objACL
```